# bootstrap selectpicker knockoutjs disable option

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following binding in [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/1/).

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div>Name : <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </div>The select control should be below
    <select multiple data-bind="selectPicker: teamID, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue : 'id', selectPickerOptions: { optionsArray: teamItems, disabledOption: IsDisabled }"></select>
    <div>Selected Value(s)
        <div data-bind="text: teamID"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am thinking of doing this disabledOption: IsDisabled  and then adding

```
this.teamItems = ko.observableArray([{
         text: 'Chris',
         id: 1,
         IsDisabled: false
     }, {
     text: 'Peter',
     id: 2,
     IsDisabled: false
 }, {
     text: 'John',
     id: 3,
     IsDisabled: false

 }]);
```

I would like to know how to disable an option in the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), there's an example that shows how you can disable an item using an `optionsAfterRender` method.

About the method you can pass to it:

- It has to be in your viewmodel, not in your items
- It takes in the option HTML node, and the item it's bound to

So step one is to find a place to store which items are disabled. The easiest option would be to store it inside your `teamItems`' objects:

```
{
  text: 'Chris',
  id: 1,
  disable: ko.observable(true)
}
```

Now, we need to add a method that takes in an item and creates a binding. We can take this straight from the example:

```
this.setOptionDisable = function(option, item) {
  ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {
    disable: item.disable
  }, item);
}
```

Finally, we need to tell knockout to call this method:

```
<select multiple data-bind="optionsAfterRender: setOptionDisable, ...
```

Note that after changing a `disable` property in one of your items, you'll have to call `teamItems.valueHasMutated` manually.

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nq56p9fz/